# git pull or git checkout to deploy

Tags: git, deployment, live

What is the right way to deploy to servers - is it

> git pull

in the working directory (/var/www/myproject)

or

> git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject --git-dir=/srv/git/myproject.git checkout -f

Both would need a post-receive hook in a bare repo. I tested both, they work either way, but whatś best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use a git repo in server to trigger a build. You should separate repository and deploy server.

The best way is just use a post-receive (push) hook to trigger a build in CI server. Then CI could just package whole server code and change config, then copy to target server, stop old one, do some upgrade stuff and start new one.

The good one is that you could use symbol link to switch old and new code to reduce inconsistency when copy.

You could use Jenkins, GoCD, TeamCity and so on as CI server.

Comment: Why should'nt I, is there a valid reason?

Comment: For safety and speed, you don't want your code history is stolen by hackers and want to speed up the whole build process. If you have intrest on continuous deploy, you could look [Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation (Addison-Wesley Signature Series (Fowler)): Jez Humble, David Farley: 9780321601919: Amazon.com: Books](https://www.amazon.com/Continuous-Delivery-Deployment-Automation-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321601912). This book has a good explanation about how to do it right.